# Find class probabilities in matlab PNN and make ROC plot

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, roc

I have a Probablistic Neural Network classification experiment set up in MATLAB. I can get the classes for unseen data using the `sim` command. Is there any way I can get the probabilities for the classes that the classifier calculates? Also, is there any direct way to plot the Reciever Operating Characterstic curve and calculate the Area Under the ROC for my classifier?

Answer (score 2):

if you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use **[perfcurve](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/perfcurve.html)** function added in recent versions of MATLAB to plot ROC curves and get AUC.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck getting a response if you include a little more background and define your terms.  I recognize ROC as receiver operating characteristic curve, but PNN and AUC are just alphabet soup to me.  Don't make the mistake of assuming that someone outside of your very specific problem domain cannot help you.  You have to build a bit of a language bridge by explaining your jargon first, though.  This has the added advantage of making this particular question more useful to the stackoverflow community at large when it is eventually answered.